# How to catch exception in async context

Tags: javascript, events, jestjs, eventemitter

I'm facing a problem of exception catching when the context is `async`.

Here is my minimal reproducible code

```js
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');
const delaySync = function(ttd) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(0), ttd);
  });
};

const myEvent = new EventEmitter();
myEvent.on('something', async () => {
  console.log('Event triggered');

  // Just delay for 100ms and then throw
  await delaySync(100);

  throw new Error('Something happened');
});

describe('Events', () => {

  it('should catch error', async () => {
    await expect(myEvent.emit('something')).rejects.toThrow('Something happened');
  });

});
```

Basically, I have an event emitter. It has a callback attached on event 'something' which is async. There are some async jobs inside and after `100ms` delay it throws an error.

Normally I'd catch such errors in jest using `await expect(fn).rejects.toThrow(...)` however this case is different because `expect` fn expects a promise and `myEvent.emit('something')` is regular non-promise context.

In this case, I'm getting an error

```
● Events › should catch error

    expect(received).rejects.toThrow()

    Matcher error: received value must be a promise or a function returning a promise

    Received has type:  boolean
    Received has value: true
...
(node:20242) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Something happened
```

I've tried it with try-catch block as well but it did not work (not able to catch at all);

```js
try {
  myEvent.emit('something');
  await delaySync(250);
} catch (e) {
  expect(e.message).toBe('Something happened');
}
```

I've tried

```js
 // Not throwing because exception is not happening right away
 expect(() => myEvent.emit('something')).toThrow('Something happened');
```

Also this

```js
expect(async () => {   
  // Will thow after 100ms
  myEvent.emit('something');
  await delaySync(250);
}).toThrow('Something happened');
```

But no luck with any of them.

Any ideas on how can I catch the error in this case? or any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Eventemitter` is fully `sync` and there is no workaround for it. What you can do is to use the [eventemitter2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter2) module to replace the original `Eventemitter` class. It is fully compatible with `Eventemitter` and allows you to use `async` actions.

```js
var EventEmitter = require('eventemitter2');

const delaySync = function (ttd) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(0), ttd);
  });
};

const myEvent = new EventEmitter();
myEvent.on('something', async () => {
  console.log('Event triggered');

  // Just delay for 100ms and then throw
  await delaySync(100);

  throw new Error('Something happened');

  // for async emitters pass promisify true.
}, { promisify: true });

describe('Events', () => {
  it('should catch error', async () => {
    await expect(myEvent.emit('something')).rejects.toThrow('Something happened');
  });

}
```

Comment: `eventemitter2 ` should work pretty well for me. Thanks 